# VSTS build Copy Files task copies full path to destination

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using a *Copy Files* task in a VSTS build to copy the results of a VS project (`bin\Release` folder) to a subfolder in the staging directory.

[image: Copy Files task]

What I expect is that the contents of the `bin` folder should be in the `staging\bin` folder:

```
drop\bin\
```

but instead it copies the full path to the the destination.  So my binaries are all in

```
drop\bin\src\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Release\
```

Is there a way to copy just the files in my release folder to the staging folder without copying the full path?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So it turns out I just needed to change my source directory to the folder where the binaries were.

[image]

> **NOTE** This only works because I know exactly where the desired files are.  If you find this and you're trying to copy from multiple directories, you have a couple options:
>
> 1. Multiple *Copy Files* tasks
> 2. Just deal with the extra directories.

Answer (score 5):

Advanced => check `Flatten Folders` or `flattenFolders: true` in the YAML file.

I'm guessing this option didn't exist back then.

Comment: What if I don't want to flatten?

Comment: @Dims Then you can set it to false.

Comment: @Zimano but I still need to copy the tree

Answer (score 2):

Worthwhile to mention it helps if you use BuildConfiguration variable so it doesn't break when you use a different build config:
[image: BuildConfiguration screenshot]